# Check who is accessing my shared folders in Linux?

Tags: linux, samba

Is there any utility that shows, who is accessing( has accessed ) my shared folders. I am using samba to share folders with other windows machines.

Comment: I'd be curious if `net rap session` can show this information to you.

Answer (score 2):

Log files are in /var/log/samba

Answer (score 1):

```
net status sessions

net status shares
```

Another way is to put `utmp = yes` in the `[global]` section of `smb.conf`. After that, Samba sessions will be listed by the `w` and `who` commands, along with SSH connections.

Comment: smbstatus does the same job too

Comment: I am looking for getting the the information about users who `accessed` my shares. Not only people `accessing` my shares